# Is there an iOS equivalent to Android's Immersive Mode?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

In android there is a [relatively new 'Immersive Mode'](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) which basically lets your app overlay itself on top of the OS.

Is there an equivalent for iOS devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen such a thing. I don't see why there's a need for Immersive Mode for iPhone, when full screen applications like Fruit Ninja can be quit using the physical Home Button. This differs from Android, where the Home button is part of the software.

Comment: How does the existence of a hardware home button make the functionality introduced in Android's Immersive Mode unnecessary?

Comment: Immersive Mode enables an "immersive" experience through the use of a full screen application which disables the home button and back button. To exit the application, the user has to swipe from the top or left side of the screen. These gestures aren't necessary on iOS, as the physical Home key is always accessible to the user.